# Bad outgoing connection in Azure VM

Tags: azure, database-connection

I have a virtual machine with CentOs in Azure. Running a web-based application with a connection to the database (via public endpoint).

There is one machine with CentOs, which runs a database (MySQL). Approximately 30% of the connections to the database from the web application failed.

I also use API Facebook, and there are also problems with the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the size of your Azure VM? Please note that there are I/O quotas applied to each VM size. Thus XS sized VM has just 20mbps connection, where XL can be up to 1Gbps.
Also please make sure you have Azure VM in an Azure Data Centre location which is closest to your MySQL Db.

I run a code that utilizes FB API on Medium sized VM (Worker Role) and don't have issues with it.

Comment: Both virtual machines - small instance. VMs are placed in one area, but in different accounts. The web application has a 20 GB incoming traffic per day.
I tried to find information about I/O quotas in Azure, but found nothing. Only the fact that the speed of the internate channel may moderated.

Comment: Sorry, not small. Is medium instance.

Comment: try with bigger instance for about 24 hours to see whether there will be improvement. It is really hard to find the network bandwidth throttle limits per VM size :| 20GB/day is quite substantial even for medium. It of course depends how it is distributed during the day - all at once, or 2 times per 10G, or 20 times per 1G or 100 times per 2M ...